# Which is better: UPS or Voltage stablizer in terms of power fluctuations

Tags: lighting

I am renovating my showroom and, already having a old voltage stablizer, my question is which is better: UPS or voltage stablizer, in terms of voltage fluctuations?

Comment: What are you powering in the showroom?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know a UPS is a voltage stabilizer but with a backup battery and a voltage stabilizer is a UPS without a backup battery. As such their ability to handle voltage fluctuation depends more on their specific design than whether or not they have battery backup.

Comment: Not all UPS's have a voltage stabilizer, some just have a cut off - below this they switch to battery. Better ones will actually autoregulate the voltage (up or down) if needed. But auto-ranging computer power supplies don't really care about voltage, so it's unnecessary to stabilize it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain what you mean by "voltage stabilizer", but I'm assuming you mean something like this [Automatic Voltage Regulator from APC](http://www.apc.com/products/family/?id=67) or [Line Conditioner / AVR from Tripp Lite](http://www.tripplite.com/line-conditioner-1200w-avr-system-automatic-voltage-regulator-power-conditioner-ac-surge-protector~LC1200/) (or maybe a larger industrial model if you're powering an entire showroom)

These devices will automatically step up or step down the voltage with in a limited range  of input values (typically 90 - 140V) to output a steady 120VAC to your equipment (or 220VAC depending on your application). I believe these devices generally operate on the same principal with a multi-tap transformer and automatic switching between taps to keep the output voltage constant. (for more demanding applications, some voltage regulators may convert AC input voltage to DC and use that to feed an inverter to output AC... some UPS's work this way too)

Many (but not all) UPS's can perform the same AVR function to step up or step down a voltage without switching to battery, along with the added ability to switch to battery if the voltage exceeds the AVR range. Additionally, the UPS can switch to battery if the input frequency is too far out of range (as might be experienced with a generator)

That makes the UPS more flexible, but also more costly with greater complexity and maintenance -- the UPS has batteries, charging circuitry, and an inverter that does not exist on an AVR. If the UPS frequently needs to resort to battery power (especially if it discharges the battery significantly), the battery lifetime will be reduced.

Unless you need the battery backup capability of a UPS, I'd probably recommend sticking with the voltage stabilizer since it's generally less expensive and should be more reliable since it's a simpler product with fewer potential sources of failure and no batteries to maintain and replace. Both should be equally effective at smoothing out most voltage fluctuations.